# Container shrinks to the size of his child

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Why is my Container shrinks to the size of his child?
By the way, the container doesn't shrink if he is in slivers

```
Container(
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue[50],
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                      offset: Offset(3.0, 10.0),
                      // spreadRadius: 2.0,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                child: Icon(Icons.location_on,
                    color: Color(0XFF0D47A1), size: 60.0),
              ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that widgets size themselves is actually quite complicated, and I don't think I can do a better job explaining than flutter's documentation: [Layouts in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout). Different widget types size themselves differently depending on their children and their parents. So when a container is in a SliverList it might size itself differently than if it isn't.

However, the `alignment` property of the Container defines how the container sizes itself:

> If non-null, the container will expand to fill its parent and position its child within itself according to the given value. If the incoming constraints are unbounded, then the child will be shrink-wrapped instead.

You could alternatively wrap the child in a `Center` or `Alignment` widget.

Comment: Somehow it work great only inside Column&Stack but not inside a row